# commentry on durga dwatrimsha namavali stotram

Tags: sanskrit, durga

Can anyone share a reference on some good commentary on [durga dwatrimsha namavali stotram](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/durgaa32.html)?

Most the references i find directly gives meanings without root word or sandhi.